# Lodash Dead Code Removal in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash, webpack, babeljs, uglifyjs

I've been using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) in my applications and libraries and I've been packaging my applications and libraries with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) (and [UglifyJS](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin)).

The problem with this is that when minifying, if you imported lodash in its entirety, UglifyJS doesn't know to remove the functions from lodash that are unused.  Clever people have come up with importing just the functions you're going to use from lodash, like so:

```
var forEach = require('lodash/array/forEach');
```

This works great and results in a much smaller compiled version of my code.  However, it can be very tedious in files that use many parts of lodash.

Can the same effect be achieved using ES6-style imports and [Babel](http://babeljs.io/)'s [DCE transformer](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/minification/dead-code-elimination/)?  For example:

```
import { forEach } from 'lodash';
```

I'm suspicious since it's importing from the the root of the lodash library and not from the individual function's file like the former example.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your actual question, and I don't know too much about it but I think that's the goal of https://github.com/rollup/rollup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given you are likely using Babel already, I think [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash) can do the trick. It is able to perform transformation from

```
import lodash from 'lodash';

lodash.map([1, 2, 3], function(x) {
    // ... 
});
```

to

```
import _map from 'lodash/collection/map';

_map([1, 2, 3], function(x) {
    // ... 
});
```

**IMPORTANT!** As mentioned by @reflog at comments, this approach doesn't work with lodash chaining!

Comment: That's awesome.  I had no idea that existed.  Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that it doesn't work with chaining. So if you try ```_(array).map(func).tap(log)``` it will not work.

Comment: @reflog Thanks. Added a note.